# How to show relationship between schemas in mongodb like in sql database?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose-schema

I have got two models one is "Posts" and another one is "Comments". I want to show relationship between these two models which is a single post has may comments, but i am stuck here. I know how to show these kind of relationship in sql database. Currently i am using mongoose-schema and node js.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make relation in between `Posts` and `Comments` schema

// Comments Schema

```
var CommentSchema = new Schema({
       // your fields
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('Comments', CommentSchema);
```

// Post schema

```
var PostSchema = new Schema({
       // your fields
       comments:[{
          type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
          ref:'Comments'
       }],
});
 // so in comments you will store comments._id values
module.exports = mongoose.model('Posts', PostSchema);
```

Comment: ok i got this one but could you please tell me how can i add new post through nodejs like req.body.title

Comment: this is not related this question . If this answer solved your problem then you should accept and vote up and post new question for new problem then someone may will help you for new problem @user3869304